# Executing a whole js file as a module in Chromium Embedded Framework

Tags: javascript, module, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I am using the Chromium Embedded Framework in C# (cefSharp) als testing platform for a software I am currently working on. In these tests i use the cefSharp to inject my js file on various websites. Up till now my software consistet of one big js file and i was able to inject it in following way.

```
        //Wait for the MainFrame to finish loading
        Browser.FrameLoadEnd += (sender, args) =>
        {
            //Wait for the MainFrame to finish loading
            if (args.Frame.IsMain)
            {
                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes("../../js/myJs.js");
                string script = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                Browser.ShowDevTools();
           
                Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync(script);
            };

        };
```

This solution worked fine.
Now i refactored some code and split my js file up into multiple modules.
If i execute the modules the same way i did with the previous js file i instantly get errors stating "import statements can only be used in modules". (normally the fix for it would be simply to reference the js file as "module" in the html file instead of "text/javascript") Because I´m injecting it via cef i cant do that. My question is: Is there a possibility to run this js modules as modules via cefSharp?

Comment: Are you using CefSharp?  Please add the relevant tag. You can probably serve the js using a resource handler and execute js to create the html script tags. https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/wiki/General-Usage#loading-htmlcssjavascriptetc-from-diskdatabaseembedded-resourcestream (assuming you are using CefSharp)

Comment: Thanks you are correct it`s cefSharp I added the tag.

Comment: You can serve a file from risk as if a network request was made, calling RegisterResourceHandler specifying a url and mimeType is one option. Then execute js to load the files.

Comment: *file from disk

Comment: You can possibly turn your js into a data uri and call import, not a lot of examples out there on this, I did find one so you'll have to test and report back. https://2ality.com/2019/10/eval-via-import.html

Comment: ok so till now i created a ResourceHandler and registed it on the html page.
Does somebody know if i have to manually activate/call it from a javascript method or can i call it with a c# call?

Comment: I don't quite understand. If you register a `ResourceHandler` you can access it from within the browser like loading any other resource.

Comment: so if i register the ResourceHandler the resource should show up in the header of the html?

Comment: No. Register a ResourceHandler and then inject/execute  some JavaScript to load the resource.

Comment: Ok lets say i registered the ResourceHandler like this:

Browser.RegisterResourceHandler("localhost:7000", mStrm, "module", true);
(mStrm is the script file encoded as utf8 stream) 
How can i access it from within another js file?

Comment: How would you access it if you were connecting to a webserver?  Use a unique host name rather than specifying a port.  Use the correct mimeType for your resource. http://cefsharp.github.io/api/84.4.x/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_RegisterResourceHandler.htm when a request is made for the specified url the given response will be used, no network request is made, domain doesn't nedd to exist,  you can use an existing url to provide a custom response.  It's not a JavaScript specific feature.